# AC600 wireless NIC will not turn on

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless

I have a brand new Blueshadow AC600 wireless NIC

[amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B077XJB1Z8)

That came with a drivers disk that claimed Linux as an option.

The driver installation succeeded but

```
lsusb
```

and

```
ifconfig -a
```

fail to show the device.

I found numerous other people that used the

```
rtl88x2BU_WiFi_linux_v5.3.1_27678.20180430_COEX20180427-5959
```

Drivers, but following the dkms installation (error free), I still cannot see the NIC

lsmod:

```
Inspiron-laptop:~/Documents/code/temp$ lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
88x2bu               3158016  0
8812au                991232  0
rfcomm                 81920  16
vboxnetadp             28672  0
vboxnetflt             28672  0
vboxdrv               487424  2 vboxnetadp,vboxnetflt
ccm                    20480  9
cmac                   16384  5
algif_hash             16384  2
algif_skcipher         16384  2
af_alg                 24576  10 algif_hash,algif_skcipher
bnep                   24576  2
mei_hdcp               24576  0
intel_rapl_msr         20480  0
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     61440  1
snd_hda_codec_conexant    28672  1
x86_pkg_temp_thermal    20480  0
snd_hda_codec_generic    81920  1 snd_hda_codec_conexant
intel_powerclamp       20480  0
coretemp               20480  0
snd_hda_intel          53248  4
snd_intel_dspcfg       24576  1 snd_hda_intel
kvm_intel             282624  0
snd_hda_codec         131072  4 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_conexant,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel
snd_hda_core           90112  5 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_conexant,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec
snd_hwdep              20480  1 snd_hda_codec
kvm                   663552  1 kvm_intel
snd_pcm               106496  5 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_core
uvcvideo               98304  0
videobuf2_vmalloc      20480  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_memops       20480  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
videobuf2_v4l2         24576  1 uvcvideo
crct10dif_pclmul       16384  1
dell_laptop            24576  0
ledtrig_audio          16384  3 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_conexant,dell_laptop
videobuf2_common       49152  2 videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo
ghash_clmulni_intel    16384  0
dell_smm_hwmon         20480  0
rt2800usb              32768  0
rt2x00usb              24576  1 rt2800usb
snd_seq_midi           20480  0
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
rt2800lib             131072  1 rt2800usb
videodev              225280  3 videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo,videobuf2_common
hid_sensor_gyro_3d     20480  0
hid_sensor_rotation    20480  0
rt2x00lib              61440  3 rt2800usb,rt2x00usb,rt2800lib
snd_rawmidi            36864  1 snd_seq_midi
mc                     53248  4 videodev,videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo,videobuf2_common
btusb                  57344  0
hid_sensor_incl_3d     20480  0
btrtl                  24576  1 btusb
hid_sensor_magn_3d     20480  1
hid_sensor_als         20480  1
btbcm                  16384  1 btusb
hid_sensor_accel_3d    20480  1
joydev                 24576  0
btintel                24576  1 btusb
hid_sensor_trigger     20480  12 hid_sensor_gyro_3d,hid_sensor_incl_3d,hid_sensor_als,hid_sensor_accel_3d,hid_sensor_magn_3d,hid_sensor_rotation
industrialio_triggered_buffer    16384  6 hid_sensor_gyro_3d,hid_sensor_incl_3d,hid_sensor_als,hid_sensor_accel_3d,hid_sensor_magn_3d,hid_sensor_rotation
kfifo_buf              16384  1 industrialio_triggered_buffer
hid_sensor_iio_common    20480  7 hid_sensor_gyro_3d,hid_sensor_trigger,hid_sensor_incl_3d,hid_sensor_als,hid_sensor_accel_3d,hid_sensor_magn_3d,hid_sensor_rotation
aesni_intel           372736  13
iwlmvm                380928  0
industrialio           73728  12 industrialio_triggered_buffer,hid_sensor_gyro_3d,hid_sensor_trigger,hid_sensor_incl_3d,kfifo_buf,hid_sensor_als,hid_sensor_accel_3d,hid_sensor_magn_3d,hid_sensor_rotation
crypto_simd            16384  1 aesni_intel
snd_seq                69632  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
cryptd                 24576  4 crypto_simd,ghash_clmulni_intel
mac80211              843776  4 iwlmvm,rt2x00lib,rt2x00usb,rt2800lib
glue_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
intel_cstate           20480  0
bluetooth             581632  49 btrtl,btintel,btbcm,bnep,btusb,rfcomm
intel_rapl_perf        20480  0
libarc4                16384  1 mac80211
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi
ecdh_generic           16384  2 bluetooth
ecc                    28672  1 ecdh_generic
snd_timer              36864  2 snd_seq,snd_pcm
i915                 1986560  58
iwlwifi               331776  1 iwlmvm
dell_wmi               20480  0
dell_smbios            28672  2 dell_wmi,dell_laptop
dcdbas                 20480  1 dell_smbios
intel_hid              20480  0
input_leds             16384  0
wmi_bmof               16384  0
serio_raw              20480  0
dell_wmi_descriptor    20480  2 dell_wmi,dell_smbios
snd                    90112  18 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_seq,snd_hda_codec_conexant,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_timer,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi
cfg80211              704512  5 iwlmvm,88x2bu,rt2x00lib,iwlwifi,mac80211
drm_kms_helper        184320  1 i915
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 i915
soundcore              16384  1 snd
hid_multitouch         28672  0
fb_sys_fops            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
syscopyarea            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
processor_thermal_device    24576  0
sysfillrect            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
mei_me                 40960  1
intel_rapl_common      24576  2 intel_rapl_msr,processor_thermal_device
intel_xhci_usb_role_switch    16384  0
sysimgblt              16384  1 drm_kms_helper
mei                   106496  3 mei_hdcp,mei_me
roles                  16384  1 intel_xhci_usb_role_switch
intel_soc_dts_iosf     20480  1 processor_thermal_device
intel_vbtn             20480  0
soc_button_array       20480  0
sparse_keymap          16384  3 intel_hid,dell_wmi,intel_vbtn
int3403_thermal        16384  0
int3402_thermal        16384  0
int340x_thermal_zone    16384  3 int3403_thermal,int3402_thermal,processor_thermal_device
mac_hid                16384  0
acpi_pad              184320  0
int3400_thermal        20480  0
acpi_thermal_rel       16384  1 int3400_thermal
sch_fq_codel           20480  5
parport_pc             40960  0
ppdev                  24576  0
lp                     20480  0
parport                53248  3 parport_pc,lp,ppdev
drm                   491520  22 drm_kms_helper,i915
ip_tables              32768  0
x_tables               40960  1 ip_tables
autofs4                45056  2
hid_sensor_custom      24576  0
hid_sensor_hub         24576  9 hid_sensor_gyro_3d,hid_sensor_trigger,hid_sensor_iio_common,hid_sensor_incl_3d,hid_sensor_als,hid_sensor_accel_3d,hid_sensor_magn_3d,hid_sensor_rotation,hid_sensor_custom
ums_realtek            24576  1
uas                    28672  0
usb_storage            77824  2 uas,ums_realtek
usbhid                 57344  0
hid_generic            16384  0
crc32_pclmul           16384  0
psmouse               155648  0
intel_lpss_pci         20480  0
i2c_i801               32768  0
ahci                   40960  3
i2c_hid                28672  0
intel_lpss             16384  1 intel_lpss_pci
idma64                 20480  0
libahci                32768  1 ahci
virt_dma               20480  1 idma64
wmi                    32768  4 dell_wmi,wmi_bmof,dell_smbios,dell_wmi_descriptor
hid                   131072  5 i2c_hid,usbhid,hid_multitouch,hid_sensor_hub,hid_generic
video                  49152  3 dell_wmi,dell_laptop,i915
pinctrl_sunrisepoint    28672  0
pinctrl_intel          28672  1 pinctrl_sunrisepoint
```

How do I install the AC600 wireless NIC on Ubuntu 20.04?

Note:

I can plug the NIC into a Windows box and it turns on just fine.

Update:

dmesg following NIC insert into USB

```
[115260.539887] usb 1-2: new high-speed USB device number 24 using xhci_hcd
[115260.696155] usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=0bda, idProduct=c811, bcdDevice= 2.00
[115260.696158] usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[115260.696159] usb 1-2: Product: 802.11ac NIC
[115260.696161] usb 1-2: Manufacturer: Realtek
[115260.696162] usb 1-2: SerialNumber: 123456
[115291.567353] usb 1-2: USB disconnect, device number 24
[115294.691861] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 25 using xhci_hcd
[115294.844276] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0bda, idProduct=c811, bcdDevice= 2.00
[115294.844280] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[115294.844281] usb 1-1: Product: 802.11ac NIC
[115294.844283] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: Realtek
[115294.844285] usb 1-1: SerialNumber: 123456
```

Comment: It looks be be a power issue on the USB bus or you may have a bad USB port

Comment: use this driver for support of the latest version of the Linux kernel.  https://github.com/morrownr/8821cu-20210916

Answer (score 0):

Plug in your wifi adaptor. Run the following command in terminal

```
sudo dmesg
```

In the output that follows, check for any "red lines", which indicate errors. In one of those red lines, your wifi adaptor's driver file/s may be mentioned. If you find such a line with the driver file name written on it, copy the file name. Make sure that in /etc/apt/sources.list , "contrib non-free" is written at the end of each line of the sources.

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt-cache search <file-name-u-saw>
```

If an output appears, it means a driver is available at the apt repository with the name of driver written in the output.

```
sudo apt-get install <driver-name-u-saw-after-running-the-last-command>
```

Comment: I didn't get an error message when I plugged in the device to my USB

Comment: Did you run the dmesg command? It would show some red lines as errors.

Comment: The only red lines in dmesg was for some ACPI stuff, that I am extremely confident is unrelated. USB insert went error free.

Comment: If the manufacturer is realtek, try installing this: sudo apt-get install firmware-realtek

Comment: E: Package 'firmware-realtek' has no installation candidate

Comment: did you add "contrib non-free" to the end of each source in /etc/apt/sources.list? After doing this, update apt and try installing firmware-realtek again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111441/discussion-between-losnihcil-and-brad).

Answer (score 0):

> idVendor=0bda, idProduct=c811

Your 0bda:c811 device is, in fact, an 8821cu device. Your lsmod shows that you have loaded the following: 88x2bu, 8812au, rt2800usb (a Ralink driver) and iwlwifi (an Intel driver). None are correct for your device. While having the incorrect driver loaded probably does no harm, it also, as you have seen, does not help.

Note: the driver iwlwifi is a PCI driver; the remainder are USB. Do you have an internal Intel wireless in your laptop? Why are you installing a USB device instead of using the usually superior Intel? Should we troubleshoot the internal device instead?

Let's install the correct driver:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install --reinstall build-essential git dkms
git clone https://github.com/brektrou/rtl8821CU.git
cd rtl8821CU
chmod +x dkms-install.sh
sudo ./dkms-install.sh
```

Reboot.